# How to present fitted values and CIs from a regression analysis

Tags: r, intervals

I conducted a regression analysis in R and obtained fitted values and their confidence intervals. Now, I need to present them in a report. I want to present the fitted values and their confidence intervals in the same plot. Does any one know how to do it? Or, does anyone have a better idea on presenting the fitted values and the CIs some other way?

Comment: `coefplot` in the `arm` package, `plotCI` in the `plotrix` package, `coefplot2` from R-forge ...

Comment: oh, and the `coefplot` package as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to give more information about the specifics of your problem for us to be able to give a fuller answer but since another way of looking at confidence intervals is as error-bars how about looking at this ...
http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Plotting%20means%20and%20error%20bars%20(ggplot2)/

or

http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_errorbar.html

Comment: I have taken a look at the links, but they are not what I am looking for. I want to present the fitted values (Y^hat) on the y axis versus the observed values (Y) on the x axis adding a straight line (not fluctuated) . In addition, I want to put  two dashed lines showing the lower limit and upper limit of the CI.